# Swift compile time error when passing object with generics subclass type constraint to method

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a class with a generic type and the generic type has a subclass type constraint. I then try and pass an instance of the class to a method but end up with the following compile time error:

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'B<SomeType>' to expected argument type 'B<NSObject>'
```

Below is a simple example:

```
class A: NSObject {

    func testB(b: B<NSObject>) {

    }
}

class B<SomeType: NSObject>: NSObject {

    func test() {
        let a = A()
        a.testB(b: self) // <----- The error noted above is shown here
    }
}
```

Because `SomeType` is guaranteed to be a subclass of `NSObject`, I would have expected the compiler would be ok with converting `B<SomeType>` to `B<NSObject>` and passing it along.

Class A only cares that B's `SomeType` is a subclass of `NSObject` and not about the actual type of `SomeType`. It's like if a function were to take a `UIView` parameter and you pass in a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
func testB(b: B<NSObject>) {

}
```

To:

```
func testB<SomeType: NSObject>(b: B<SomeType>) {

}
```

This will work, because `SomeType` is constrain to `NSObject`, not equal to  `NSObject`.

So your function's  `SomeType` should be constrain to `NSObject` too:

`func testB<SomeType: NSObject>(b: B<SomeType>) { ... }`