# Swift compile time errors when using generics and accessing dictionary's values

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, generics

Below I have a class, `B`, with a generic type and the generic type has a subclass type constraint. In a separate class, `A`, I create a dictionary property, `values`, with the key as `String` and value as `B`. Class `A` then has methods to return or set values in the dictionary such that the values are not constrained to a single type (they maintain their generic `SomeType` type which is a subclass of `NSObject`). However, this produces the following two errors noted inline below:

```
class A: NSObject {

    var values = [String : B]()

    func get<SomeType: NSObject>(key: String) -> B<SomeType>? { 
        // #1 Error on line below: cannot convert return expression of type 'B<NSObject>?' to return type 'B<SomeType>?'
        return values[key]
    }

    func set<SomeType: NSObject>(key: String, value: B<SomeType>) {
        // #2 Error on line below: cannot assign value of type 'B<SomeType>' to type 'B<NSObject>?'
        values[key] = value
    }
}

class B<SomeType: NSObject>: NSObject {

}
```

I've attempted various forms of declaring the `values` dictionary to tell the compiler that `SomeType` is a subclass of `NSObject` and everything is going to be ok, but have been unsuccessful. Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41475747/4147791), I'm a bit stumped because the methods define `SomeType` as a subclass of `NSObject` and therefore things appear to be type safe when setting and getting from `values`.

I could remove the generic types from the methods and instead force the type to be `<NSObject>`, but then I'd run into the same problem as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41475747/4147791).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be doing what you think it's doing:

```
var values = [String : B]()
```

This isn't really `[String : B]`, it's `[String : B<NSObject>]`. (I'm actually kind of surprised that this is legal syntax; I'd be tempted to open a bugreport about that; `B` isn't a proper type in Swift.) You may realize this already, but it's the first important note.

The second important note is that generic types are not covariant in Swift. A `Thing<Cat>` is not a subtype of `Thing<Animal>`. There are some type-theory reasons for this, and there are some technical implementation reasons for this, but the important fact is that it's not possible in Swift.

If you need to hold a variety of `B` types, then you'll need to build a [type eraser](http://robnapier.net/erasure). In your case, the type eraser could possibly be `B<NSObject>` with something like this:

```
class B<SomeType: NSObject>: NSObject {
    let value: SomeType

    init(value: SomeType) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func liftGeneric() -> B<NSObject> {
        return B<NSObject>(value: value)
    }
}
```

If you need to hold just one kind of `B` type, then make `A` generic as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as using type eraser, I assume I would then be able to remove the generics from the `get` method and just return `B<NSObject>?` and then in the `set` method set the value using `values[key] = value.liftGeneric()`? However, in that case you're setting a copy of value to the dictionary rather than the actual value passed in. Is there a way to still set the instance of value passed in using this method?

Comment: No. You would have to wrap it into a more complicated type eraser in that case, something that retained the original object and passed messages to it. In most cases I've found that solutions that run too deeply into this have over-genericized and should go back to the explicit problem being solved (I mean the actual problem in the code in front of you today, rather than generic solutions to solve problems you may have some day). Sometimes you really benefit from generics, but we built a lot of good software w/ no generics all for many years… If you're running into walls, back up.

Comment: (Regarding building the more complicated class-based type eraser, I'd need to see an explicit problem. There's no good one-size-fits-all there. It depends, and there are many tradeoffs. There's no "this just fixes it all for you" solution.)

Comment: Cool, yeah I was starting to feel like I was going deeper and deeper down the rabbit hole. What I initially started out trying to do didn't seem that crazy, or over engineered, but things started getting messy fast. I'll go back to what I had before and rethink things. Thanks, again.